# Trying to change gradle file so 2 apps can share code

Tags: android

I'm trying to make the correct changes to the gradle files so I can share code in android studio

I added the following line to each appos gradle file
  compile project`(':common')`  in the dependencies block.

in stack over flow they mention that I have to add the line
 include `':library'`, `':module'`

But I don't understand where I put this.
from stack overflow:

> "In that top-level settings.gradle you have  include `':library'`,
>   `':module'`"

I looked for a gradle file that would have settings in its name but did not find any matching names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File `settings.gradle` must be in top-level folder of your project. It contains string: `include ':module0', ':module1'` — `moduleN` are names of your app modules.

So firstly you need to create module (if you will do this with Android Studio `File -> New -> New module`, all necessary actions will be done by Android Studio). And then you can add your own module to dependencies of other modules: `implementation project(':module1')`.